# Use of CASE in LIMIT on MySQL

Tags: php, if-statement, count, case

I am selecting some data using the following query. It works well. Now I set the limit as 15. I am collecting data from various sub categories. Now the data getting is a total of 15 from the whole categories. Is there any way to get 15 data on each sub category in this single query using `CASE` or `IF`

for example now it gives mobile - 5, computer - 4 and camera - 6

I need Mobile - 15, camputer - 15 and camera - 15

My Query is

```
SELECT
count_sum,
id,
NAME,
url,
price,
main_url,
sub_url,
image
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(product_count.count) AS count_sum,
        product.id,
        product. NAME,
        product.url,
        product.price,
        main_cat.main_url,
        sub_cat.sub_url
    FROM
        product_count
    JOIN product ON product_count.id_fk = product.id
    JOIN main_cat ON product.main_id = main_cat.main_id
    JOIN sub_cat ON product.sub_id = sub_cat.sub_id
    WHERE
        product_count.product_status = 'active'
    AND product. STATUS = 'active'
    GROUP BY
        product_count.id_fk
) product
JOIN image_details ON image_details.id_fk = product.id
WHERE
image_details.featured = 'yes'
GROUP BY
product. NAME
ORDER BY
count_sum DESC
LIMIT 15
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group). But it didn't work for me. Actually I didn't get the workflow. Can some please help me? I am beginer in these kind of codes. Please help